# NoAuthorizationCodeError for facebook omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I've tried everything and cant solve this NoAuthorizationCodeError error from the facebook omniauth gem.

I've basically copied and pasted railscasts ep360. I've tried to remove the coffee script, I've changed to gem vs 1.4.0, I've tried different versions of rails.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
at=info method=GET path=/auth/facebook/callback host=enigmatic-sands-2189.herokuapp.com fwd="105.228.66.17" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=27ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-10-14T19:20:29.091206+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/auth/facebook/callback host=enigmatic-sands-2189.herokuapp.com fwd="105.228.66.17" dyno=web.1 connect=14ms service=27ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-10-14T19:20:29.071596+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/auth/facebook/callback" for 105.228.66.17 at 2013-10-14 19:20:29 +0000
2013-10-14T19:20:29.075493+00:00 app[web.1]: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
2013-10-14T19:20:29.084256+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-14T19:20:29.084256+00:00 app[web.1]: OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook::NoAuthorizationCodeError (must pass either a `code` parameter or a signed request (via `signed_request` parameter or a `fbsr_XXX` cookie)):
```

Sessions controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Routes

```
    root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
```

Gem file

```
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

gem "omniauth", "~> 1.1.1"
gem "omniauth-facebook", "1.4.0"
```

User model

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    user.save!
  end
end

Initialize/omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, '51xxxxxxxxx42200', '0e3b1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4ff87'
end
```

Comment: In your facebook app on the facebook developers site, is your Site URL listed as as your the base url of your site?  ie, `http://yoursite.com` ?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to use the default herokuapp.com url enigmatic-sands-2xx9.herokuapp.com for the app domain. I changed it to localhost and it works fine. It also works if I use a custom domain. Any idea what I would enter for App Domains if the app was hosted at http://enigmatic-sands-2xx9.herokuapp.com because it isnt just enigmatic-sands-2xx9.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0):

You should have the app on your own domain. Heroku policy prevents creating cookies on *.herokuapp.com, check this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com